# I just bought an Xbox 360 game with wrong region. What should I do?

Tags: xbox-360, region-lock

I just bought a  game (Forza 4) for my Xbox 360 (bought in the US). When I tried to play the game, it wouldn't load because of region issue. Is there a legal way to solve this (no crack)?

Comment: Buy a US console and use it in the US?

Comment: Return the game?

Comment: Buy a console from each of the available regions; that way you can save yourself some money with each future game purchase by picking the cheapest region the game is released for.

Comment: @Jon W Not sure if your comment was genuine or attempted sarcasm but as a Brit now living in the US owning both a UK and US X-Box I would agree that's a perk though I kept both more for the ability to play all my existing Region 2 DVDs

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Depending on the [version of Forza 4](http://www.play-asia.com/paOS-00-3-xbox360_compatibility_guide-49-en-84-o.html) you have, you might be out of luck.  The best solution I can think of (without getting into a system hack) would be to sell your game and purchase a US-region specific or region-unlocked game.  This kind of sucks, I admit, but maybe you can get lucky with a trade.  Either that, or trade in the system.

If you own an NTSC-U/C (US and Canada) system, and you don't live or purchase games in the US or Canada, make sure the game you purchase is region free or NTSC-U/C compatible.  The regioning of a game is up to the publisher, so this will vary.

**To find out the region the game is meant for:**

On the front of the game case it will be specified below the title on the right:

[image: NTSC-J]

This title will come in 4 different varieties:

1. **NTSC | J** :  This means NTSC Japan (like the picture above)
2. **NTSC**  :  This means NTSC-U/C (US and Canada)
3. **PAL**  :  This means PAL Systems (Europe)
4. Nothing.  This will be blank.  This usually means the game is region-free.

So look for plain **NTSC** and **blank** region-labeled games, and you should be fine.