# Is Mass Effect 2 region locked?

Tags: xbox-360, mass-effect-2, region-lock

I found a Mass Effect 2 game in one of the stores in the Philippines, but they said that my Xbox must be a US Version, and that it won't work as my Xbox is a Japanese Version. I later found out on the internet that Mass Effect 2 is region free. Is it true?

Comment: Related, http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/74811/i-just-bought-an-xbox-360-game-with-wrong-region-what-should-i-do

Comment: Actually my Xbox was Jtag-ed will this do anything?

Comment: a JTAG-ed Xbox 360 has the capability of turning off region locking, though that is based off the actual modifications done.